# Make Doxygen interpret C# <code> XML documentation tag as \code

Tags: c#, doxygen

I'm working with doxygen and has encountered an issue, where the <code> in C# code documentation is interpreted differently that the \code command for doxy. Both seems to be interpreted as code, and both are typed in monospace fonts. But the \code encapsulates the code in a nice box and understands newline, while code in <code> is just printed out in one line with no box.

Is it possible to make doxy interpret <code> as \code?

Or before it interprets the documentation change the <code> to \code and </code> to \endcode to work around the problem?

I am aware I could just have \code and \endcode statements in the documented code segments, but I work with other tools like Resharper that interprets <code>, and will not understand \code. Having the code documentation as close the standard (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) makes it easier to work with different tools.

Comment: Presumably, it is interpreting `<code>` as the HTML tag, not as C#'s XML documentation tag. That explains the difference in output. I have no idea how to fix it, though.

Comment: Possibly, but I found this on their site: "<code> Set one or more lines of source code or program output. Note that this command behaves like \code ... \endcode for C# code, but it behaves like the HTML equivalent <code>...</code> for other languages." (http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/xmlcmds.html). I use .cs as the files it should look for and set the language to C# as well.

Comment: Hmm - It looks like it is a bug in doxygen: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685597. A work around is to encapsulate one of the codeblocks (or just the one) with a remarks tag. It somehow activates the correct parser and the <code> now parses correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1.8.2 version of doxygen has now fixed this error and the code tag is working as it should.

Comment: Newest is a moving target, please mention the version. The current newest version is 1.8.12 so I assume you meant this on.

Comment: @albert Fixed answer :D, it was in version 1.8.2 it was fixed